# Error when linking opencv_world and opencv_imgporc cmake

Tags: opencv, cmake, rad-studio

Since 'opencv_world.lib' is a collection of all the '.lib' files specified in CMake, I attempted to create a 'world.lib' file. However, when running the following command for Borland makefiles:

> cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=bcc32x.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=bcc32x.exe
> -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-Wno-c++11-narrowing" -G "Borland Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -DWITH_WEBP=OFF -DWITH_OPENEXR=OFF -DWITH_TIFF=OFF -DBUILD_TIFF=OFF -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF -DWITH_JASPER=OFF -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DBUILD_PROTOBUF=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_dnn=OFF -DBUILD_IPP=OFF -DWITH_IPP=OFF -DWITH_ADE=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_apps=OFF -DOPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH="C:\OpenCV\opencv_contrib-4.7.0\modules" -DBUILD_opencv_world=ON C:/openCV/opencv-4.7.0

I encountered the following error when it attempted to link the library:

> Warning: unknown command line switch 'i' ignored  Warning: unknown
> command line switch 's' ignored
>
> Error: the combinations `*+` or `+*` are not allowed
>
> ** error 1 ** deleting lib\opencv_world470d.lib
>
> ** error 1 ** deleting modules\world\CMakeFiles\opencv_world.dir\all
>
> ** error 1 ** deleting all

In an attempt to resolve this error, I systematically tested each module that can be turned off and on, identifying the modules that caused the error. One of the modules 'ml' could be easily turned off, but the 'imgproc' module can't be turned off because most modules are dependent on it. I carefully inspected each file, searching for occurrences of `*+` and `+*` and commented or deleted them when found, but the error still persists. Could someone provide guidance on how to resolve this issue and prevent the error from occurring?